# Shorten dictionary if statements

Tags: python

I was wondering how to shorten my **if statement**. It's a very big list now. but I would like to shorten it.
Unfortunately I've been looking for several things on the internet for hours, but can't really come up with a solution.

Can anyone give me a tip or give me an example in my code? (Sorry I just started few days ago with programming)

```
import time # for lockout after 5 attempts 

students = { # Make a static dictenoary called students
    1: {"name": "Daniel","lastname": "maker","email" : "daniel@email.nl","password" : "123456"},
    2: {"name": "Sandy","lastname": "Mango","email" : "sandy@email.nl","password" : "sdasdas!@"},
    3: {"name": "Kreeft","lastname": "Garnaal","email" : "Kreeft@email.nl","password" : "Mekalekkea!@"},
    4: {"name": "Alfred","lastname": "Skylake","email" : "Alfred@email.nl","password" :"suiker!@"}
}

count = 0 # Count the number of failed login attempts
while True: # Create a loop that requests and checks the credentials
    print ("")
    email = input("Enter your E-mail account: ")
    passwords = input("Enter your password: ")
    count += 1 #count the number of failed login attempts
    print ("")
    
    if (email == students[1]["email"] and passwords == students[1]["password"]): # Check credentials if it's correct on the right email and password.
        print ("Welcome",students[1]["name"],students[1]["lastname"],"you are successfully logged in!")
        break
    elif(email == students[2]["email"] and passwords == students[2]["password"]):
        print ("Welcome",students[2]["name"],students[2]["lastname"],"you are successfully logged in!")
        break
    elif (email == students[3]["email"] and passwords == students[3]["password"]):
        print ("Welcome",students[3]["name"],students[3]["lastname"],"you are successfully logged in!")
        break
    elif (email == students[4]["email"] and passwords == students[4]["password"]):
        print ("Welcome",students[4]["name"], students[4]["lastname"], "you are successfully logged in!")
        break
    elif count > 5:
        tijd = time.localtime()
        clock = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", tijd)
        print("On", clock, "You have logged incorrectly 5 times. You are blocked for 15 minutes")
        #time.sleep(900) #Sleep 15 minutes.
        break
    else:
        print ("Incorrect E-mail or password!")
        print ("")
```

Comment: ... or use the email as the key instead of that arbitrary number, then you won't need a loop at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your `if-else` statements with a simple `for` loop:

```
import time 

students = { # Make a static dictenoary called students
    1: {"name": "Daniel","lastname": "maker","email" : "daniel@email.nl","password" : "123456"},
    2: {"name": "Sandy","lastname": "Mango","email" : "sandy@email.nl","password" : "sdasdas!@"},
    3: {"name": "Kreeft","lastname": "Garnaal","email" : "Kreeft@email.nl","password" : "Mekalekkea!@"},
    4: {"name": "Alfred","lastname": "Skylake","email" : "Alfred@email.nl","password" :"suiker!@"}
}


count = 0
while True:
    email = input("\nEnter your E-mail account: ")
    passwords = input("Enter your password: ")
    count += 1 #count the number of failed login attempts
    login = False
    print ("")
    
    for student in students:
        if students[student]["email"] == email:
            if students[student]["password"] == passwords:
                print (f"Welcome, {students[student]["name"]},{students[student]["lastname"]}, you are successfully logged in!")
                count = 0
                login = True
                break
    if not login:
        print ("Incorrect E-mail or password!\n")
    if count > 5:
        current_time = time.localtime()
        clock = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", current_time)
        print("On", clock, "You have logged incorrectly 5 times. You are blocked for 15 minutes")
        #time.sleep(900) #Sleep 15 minutes.
        #count = 0 
        break
```

Comment: thanks for all your answers and tips! 

I have tested and tried all 3 codes and got it working. I understand it better now.

Yes the reason I have a while loop and unsecured passwords is because my school mandated this. Otherwise I would have done something else that made sense in practice
I already met the requirements of the assignment with my code, but I wanted to make my code better and better understand how to deal with such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension

```
selected_students = [s for s in students if s["email"] == email and s["password"] == password]
```

If len(seleced_students) == 0 then you didn't find any.

This will not break and always go through the full dict, but it more pythonic than a for and also finds if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop and use the Python feature that `for` can be combined with `else`, where the `else` part executes if no `break` statement was hit.

```
for i in students:
    # Check credentials if it's correct on the right email and password.
    if (email == students[i]["email"] and passwords == students[i]["password"]):
        print("Welcome", students[i]["name"], students[i]["lastname"], "you are successfully logged in!")
        break
    elif count > 5:
        tijd = time.localtime()
        clock = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", tijd)
        print("On", clock, "You have logged incorrectly 5 times. You are blocked for 15 minutes")
        # time.sleep(900) #Sleep 15 minutes.
        break
else:
    print("Incorrect E-mail or password!")
    print("")
```

If you can change the data structure, you might want to use the email as the key of your dictionary instead of a number.

```py
students = {  # Make a static dictenoary called students
    "daniel@email.nl": {"name": "Daniel", "lastname": "maker", "email": "daniel@email.nl", "password": "123456"},
    "sandy@email.nl": {"name": "Sandy", "lastname": "Mango", "email": "sandy@email.nl", "password": "sdasdas!@"},
    "Kreeft@email.nl": {"name": "Kreeft", "lastname": "Garnaal", "email": "Kreeft@email.nl", "password": "Mekalekkea!@"},
    "Alfred@email.nl": {"name": "Alfred", "lastname": "Skylake", "email": "Alfred@email.nl", "password": "suiker!@"}
}

[...]
    try:
        student = students[email]
        if passwords == student["password"]:
            print("Welcome", student["name"], student["lastname"], "you are successfully logged in!")
            break
        elif count > 5:
            tijd = time.localtime()
            clock = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", tijd)
            print("On", clock, "You have logged incorrectly 5 times. You are blocked for 15 minutes")
            # time.sleep(900) #Sleep 15 minutes.
            break
        else:
            print("Incorrect E-mail or password!")
            print("")
    except KeyError:
        print("Incorrect E-mail or password!")
        print("")
```

You certainly don't want to store passwords in plain text and use a hash instead.